# Set loop travel max 'n' lines

Tags: r

Ok

So I have a loop that currently finds a value that is below <-1 and will print a 1 else 0. It will then loop until it finds another value >= 1.

```
value <- c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,-2.0,0.7,0.4,-10,0.1,0.2,0.4,3.0,0.6,0.7,0.8,-1.2,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.5,2,0.1,0.2)
df <- data.frame(signal =0,value)

df$signal[[1]] = ifelse(df$value[[1]] < (-1), 1, 0)

for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$signal[i] = ifelse(df$value[i] < (-1), 1,
                        ifelse(df$value[i] >= 1, 0,
                               df$signal[i-1]))
}
df
```

What I intend to do is instead of exiting the loop >1, is exit after a fixed number of 'n' lines. 
So if i set the total loop travel to 5 lines from initial -1 find, it would print 0's after its traveled the maximum nlines of 5.

If we meet another signal 1 within the max of 5 lines travel it is to ignore this and just continue to 5 line travel.

Im thinking along the lines of setting a counter:

```
counter <- 1
repeat {
  df$signal = ifelse(df$value < (-1), 1, 0)
  counter <- counter+1

  if(counter > 5) {
    break
  }
}
```

The above seams reasonable however it not producing my result.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

a desired output would be:

```
   signal value
1       0   0.2
2       0   0.3
3       0   0.4
4       0   0.5
5       0   0.6
6       1  -2.0
7       1   0.7
8       1   0.4
9       1 -10.0
10      1   0.1
11      0   0.2
12      0   0.4
13      0   3.0
14      0   0.6
15      0   0.7
16      0   0.8
17      1  -1.2
18      1   0.6
19      1   0.7
20      1   0.8
21      1   0.3
22      0   0.5
23      0   2.0
24      0   0.1
25      0   0.2
```

Notice on each <-1.0 value we print 1 and travel for 5 lines... also on line 9, we have a repeat <1.0 while the max 5 nlines condition has not been met, this ignores repeats that are within the max 'n' lines of travel.

again line 17 we meet a <-1.0 and print 1's for max travel of 5 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
value <-c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,-2.0,0.7,0.4,-10,0.1,0.2,0.4,3.0,0.6,0.7,0.8,-1.2,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.5,2,0.1,0.2)
res <- NULL
while (length(res) < length(value)) {
   if (value[length(res)+1] < -1) {
      res <- c(res, rep(1,5))
   } else {
      res <- c(res, 0)
   }
}
res <- data.frame(signal = res, value = value)
res
```

Don't know about the counter solution. Seems to be complicated.

EDIT: You might need to do:

```
 res <- res[1:length(value)]
```

before you convert to the data frame. This ensures that your signal column is not longer than your observation/value column.